# Active perl and local encoding issue

Tags: windows, perl

am trying to using actvperrl to install prerequsist for bugzila but when trying to run this script from `cmd` running as administrator

```
 ppm install TimeDate
```

I get the following error

```
ppm install failed: The locale codeset (cp720) isn't one that perl can decode, s
topped
```

even if am using English , any idea how to fix that

Comment: Does doing `chcp 437` first (in the console from which you run `ppm`) help? Hopefully, the worse that will happen is that "é" will be displayed as "ل".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in on windows for number of the active console code page cp720.

You can change this code with command prompt by inserting chcp nnn, where nnn specifies the code page ( example :  chcp 850), you can find a list of cp here. but you must repeat the same steps each time you want to open tlmgr.
You can automate the previous steps by inserting the command chcp nnn directly in cmd.

`chcp 850`